# Laravel mail queue with custom data passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel queue to send welcome emails to my new members who sign up in my website, when I am not using queues to send the emails the emails gets sent with the custom data passed to the email template

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

Welcome {{ $member_data['name'] }}

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'htttp://google.com'])
Join WhatsApp Group
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

But when I use queues to send this same email, the job fails

```
[2022-01-24 07:02:29][28] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeMail
[2022-01-24 07:02:29][28] Failed:     App\Mail\WelcomeMail
```

My WelcomeMail.php file:

```
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->member_data = $request;
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.welcome',['member_data'=>$this->member_data])
    ->from("example@gmail.com","XYZ")
    ->subject("Welcome To Family");
}
```